# How can I extract all href's within the <main> element using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, href

I am trying to **create an array which holds all the href's within the *main* element** using javascript. Now I am not a programmer but I figured I would try and approach it in either of the two ways:

a) Isolate the *main element* (document.getElementsByTagName("main")) and then try to extract all href's from this object.

b) Create an array of all href's on the page (document.links) and then check for every href whether it has *main* as a parent node.

So far I haven't found a solution for either approach. Can anyone help me with a code fragment that creates an array with all href's within *main*? Thanks a lot in advance. I already spent hours figuring it out myself xl

Example HTML:

```
<main>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="classA">
   <a href="/pagePathA/"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="classB">
   <a href="/pagePathB/"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual code/problem so that we can help you to fix it.

Comment: You need vanilla JS or JQuery is acceptable also?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('main a[href]')` will get you all the elements with href ... from there it should be easy

Comment: @Bravo you can post this as answer

Comment: You need only elements with `href` that are direct descendants of the `main` element? Your _b)_ is suggesting this. Or all emenets with `href` below main.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Only JS. And I need all hrefs that are descendants of the main element (between <main> and </main>)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use querySelectorAll

```js
let hrefs = [...document.querySelectorAll('main a[href]')].map(({href}) => href);
console.log(hrefs);
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
  </div>
</main>
```

If you want only children of main, not all descendants

```js
let hrefs = [...document.querySelectorAll('main>a[href]')].map(({href}) => href);
console.log(hrefs);
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you Bravo, I was able to solve my issue with your help. Greatly appreciated!